# How to make interface which has a function that accepts its own type and works with interface implementations

Tags: typescript

```
interface I {
  test: (a: I) => boolean;
}

class Test implements I {

  //constructor (public additional: number) {}

  test (a: Test) { return false; }
}
```

Code works, **but** if we remove comment from constructor line **it is not working**.
The error it gives is

> Type 'I' is missing the following properties from type 'Test': additional

Now is this stupid or am I stupid? If `Test` implements `I` than it should pass as `I` in `test`?

How to organize this multiple inheritance type support?

Comment: The thing is, your interface requires a `test` method which accepts any `I`, and values of type `I` are not guaranteed to be `Test` instances. So your method doesn't work to implement the `I` interface because it only accepts `Test` instances, not all values of type `I`. The reason it works if you comment out the constructor is by accidental [structural equivalence of types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to solve this. Both with some drawbacks.

The first would be to use polymorphic `this` in the interface. This means the type of the parameter will be whatever the implementer is:

```
interface I {
  test: (a: this) => boolean;
}

class Test implements I {

  constructor (public additional: number) {}

  test (a: Test) { return false; }
}
let o:I = new Test(1); // error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4FgBQzmQDOYAXMgBRxlgAWwhAlMgLwB8yARgPZcA2EcEAG5cAX1y4EvOIULIAKhGLJgAWwAO-VRHBz02HLnwIuIYlACuCMFygV1Fjr2AJkcACbvgYYKbi8yEAtVDmgmDHFDPAIlMAoqBVjw5CgIMAsoEGR4XkIIIWRIyNx+OK4SdGZkEAgAd0TicgBGBgKAejbkaChbIA)

The problem with this approach is you lose assignability to the interface. This might be fine depending on your use case.

The other option is to use a method signature in your interface instead of a function signature. Method signatures are checked bivariantly (I have a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EInunOVRsUU) if you want to know more about variance). This means your code will be less type safe, but you can implement the class without any issues and you don't lose assignability with the `I` interface:

```
interface I {
  test(a: I): boolean;
}

class Test implements I {

  constructor (public additional: number) {}

  test (a: Test) { return this.additional === a.additional; }
}

class Test2 implements I {

  constructor (public additional2: number) {}

  test (a: Test2) { return this.additional2 === a.additional2; }
}


let o:I = new Test(1);
o.test(new Test2(1)) // this will access additional when Test2 only has additional2
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4FgBQzmQDOYAFHAFxoCUlARgPb0A2EcIA3LgL664JNxChZABUIxZMAC2ABxZSI4Yemw5c+BPRDEoAVwRh6UZCRm7aTYAmRwAJreBhgWuE0ohdU2tCqYeavAJxMBMKUWDfDGQoCDBdKBACAAtgQgA6OwcnFyZkAF4Cmwz7R2cQV3Zkf38+ASFw4gAmSVl5RTBlTF5AzW0wPQMjEzMLKxsS7PKmRvdPbyhImsCiELJKMSbI6Nj4xLAU9MzSnOaCvKKjyddGyuru3BYQ+nJ0c5AIAHcG0gBGKk4cPQ0isSO8vhswI0SH9fAB6WHJVLID7AJi5RBIeqXMquZFJRTfZpaJgAT2QSUE4yyOOmQA)

Comment: Where did you learn about typescript metaprogramming? It seems very fuzzy and run time compile time divided

Comment: A third approach is to make the interface generic: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIB4AqyIA9IgAmAzmlgHznIDeAsAFDLKTFgBcyAFHB5gJTIAvFQBGAezEAbCHBABuBgF8GDBJLjFSmCK2TAAtgAdp+iOFIZtrKnUbIEYkKygBXBGDFQuhlyMnAEZDhCQmAwYEc4SQ4QF30RaAFqZXoGJhYwLh5kKzAk5CgIMBcoEGR4SWIIOWQUlIZpTLEOSx0wKkFkEAgAdxy2zgBGPgV6IA)